# Setting a wifi on an embedded linux - not seeing wlan0 on ifconfig

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ifconfig, embedded-linux

I'm trying to set up a wifi on this linux-based embedded board which has a wifi module embedded on top of it.
I have configured `hostapd.conf` and `wpa_supplicant.conf` with the specific SSID and password.

A couple of initial questions:

- When I run `ifconfig`, I see there's no wlan0. Is that an indication that the wifi driver (wlan.ko?) isn't loaded (it doesn't exist even)?
- in order to use this wifi, is it merely a matter of running a hostapd file?
- wpa supplicant is only run if you have more than 1 devices, yeah? Hostapd running on one acting as an access point (AP), while the other being station trying to connect to the AP

distro: linux sa515m

wifi module: af50T

Comment: A Linux distro for a desktop/laptop will typically automatically download and install device drivers.  Embedded system typically have limited storage capacity, and typically require manual configuration/installation of any additional drivers.  Learn how to review the kernel boot log for which drivers were activated on your board before trying user-space or shell configuration commands.

Comment: "linux sa515m" doesn't sound like a distro name and Google doesn't return anything useful for this term. What board is it and what's the distro actually?

Comment: `uname -a` does return `Linux sa515m 4.14.190 #1 PREEMPT CST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: *"`uname -a` does return `Linux sa515m ...`"* -- Read the **man** page for the **uname** command.  That is not a *"distro"* name, but rather the "network node hostname".  IOW that is the hostname assigned by someone to that SBC.

Comment: how else do you get the distro then?